# What is NSSpeechRecognizer framework??? I can not find it?

Tags: ios, frameworks

What is NSSpeechRecognizer framework?
I was trying to find but I can't!
I tried everything but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The NSSpeechRecognizer class is the Cocoa interface to Speech
>   Recognition on OS X. Speech Recognition is architected as a “command
>   and control” voice recognition system. It uses a finite state grammar
>   and listens for phrases in that grammar. When it recognizes a phrase,
>   it notifies the client process. This architecture is different from
>   that used to support dictation.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.3 and later.

Answer (score 5):

The [`NSSpeechRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is an speech is recognizer class for Cocoa:

> The NSSpeechRecognizer class is the Cocoa interface to Speech
>   Recognition on OS X.

As state it available on OSX, but not for Cocoa Touch (iOS).